# SQL sum then find max

Tags: sql, derby

Here's [what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag2nY.png). Basically I have a relation in which I have a count for each ID and month. I'd like to sum the counts for each id by month (middle table in the picture) and then from that find the maximum value from all those sums by month, and show the month, id, and the maximum value in that order. Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT month, MAX(summed_counts) AS maximum_result
FROM
 (SELECT month, id, SUM(counts) AS summed_counts
  FROM info WHERE year=2017 GROUP BY month, id)
AS final_result GROUP BY month ORDER BY month ASC;
```

However as soon as I add `id` it no longer works:

```
SELECT month, id, MAX(summed_counts) AS maximum_result
FROM
 (SELECT month, id, SUM(counts) AS summed_counts
  FROM info WHERE year=2017 GROUP BY month, id)
AS final_result GROUP BY month, id ORDER BY month ASC;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add some sample table and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: I have -- it's in the image

Comment: This SELECT works for me in Oracle, if I remove the "AS final_result" after the inner SELECT. What SQL is it?

Comment: Which image? (I can't see any.)

Comment: @Galcoholic: I'm using Apache Derby

Comment: @jarlh: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag2nY.png

Comment: For me I can see it is working I have month, Id and maximum_results

Comment: @devil_coder: Apache Derby is weird and unintuitive. This code just won't work ᕦ(ò_óˇ)ᕤ

Comment: What does it mean "no longer works"? Do you get an error, or is the result set not what you expect?

Comment: @Derek yes may be I used SQL Server 2016. Don't have Apache Derby to test sorry

Comment: @Galcoholic: the code is not what I expect. It shows me the same as `SELECT month, id, SUM(counts) AS summed_counts FROM info WHERE year=2017 GROUP BY month, id` which is the sum of counts for each month and each id.

Comment: @devil_coder You should have, it is part of all JDKs in the "db" folder.

Comment: I don't understand why someone would vote me down?? I've done everything I've been asked to do: provided a picture, an explanation of the problem, an attempt, answered all follow up questions, and still someone voted me down!

Comment: Not me... Please, describe with words what result you would like to get, and I will try to adapt your query. For example: get the maximum sum count and the related id per month.

Comment: I think you should check this question, maybe it helps: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this (MS SQL):

```
select distinct month, 

    (select top 1 SUM(counts)
        FROM info info_detail
        WHERE year=2017 and info_detail.month=info.month
        GROUP BY id
        order by SUM(counts) desc
    ) as max_value,

    (select top 1 id 
        FROM info info_detail
        WHERE year=2017 and info_detail.month=info.month
        GROUP BY id
        order by SUM(counts) desc
    ) as max_value_id

    from info 
    where year=2017
    ORDER BY month
```

Comment: Thanks for that unfortunately it shows an error when I try it in Apache.